# Recognising if given language is regular or not

Tags: automata

L1={xy|x belongs to L and y doesn't belong to L,L is regular}
is L1 regular?
a/c to me x belongs to L so it is regular but since y doesn"t belong to L it can be regular or not.But the answer is that L1 it is regular.How can it be shown.

Comment: If `L` is regular then it must have a corresponding DFA. Then the complement of `L` is the same DFA with the accept and reject states switched.

Answer (score 0):

Regular languages are closed under complement, so if L is regular, then "not L" is regular, too.

Because they're both regular, both have DFAs. Call the DFAs M1 and M2.

An NFA for L1 can be constructed as follows:

1. Have all the states in M1 and M2
2. Have the same alphabet as M1 and M2
3. Have the initial state of M1
4. Have the accepting states of M2
5. Have the transition function include all transitions in M1 and M2, plus lambda/epsilon-transitions from states accepting in M1 to the initial state in M2

This NFA will read x in M1 at which point it can nondeterministically jump to M2 and read y, accepting its input. It can't do this unless it finds a valid x/y split. So, this NFA accepts our language, and since any language accepted by an NFA is regular, this language is regular.